# Invalid Unicode code point 0xd83f

Tags: unicode, go

I'm trying to port some Java to Go. The Java code has a character variable with the value `'\ud83f'`. When I try to use this value in Go, it doesn't compile:

```
package main
func main() {
    c := '\ud83f'
    println(c)
}
```

```
$ go run a.go
# command-line-arguments
./a.go:3: invalid Unicode code point in escape sequence: 0xd83f
```

Why? I also tried making a string with that value in Python and it worked too. It's just not working in Go for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That rune literal you tried to use is invalid because it denotes a surrogate code point. The spec says rune literals cannot denote a surrogate code point ("as well as others" (which?)):

> [Rune Literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals)
>
> [...]
>
> The escapes \u and \U represent Unicode code points so within them
>   some values are illegal, in particular those above 0x10FFFF and
>   surrogate halves.

Further below in the examples, you can see another case which is deemed illegal:

> '\U00110000' // illegal: invalid Unicode code point

Which seems to imply that invalid code points (such as those above 10ffff) are also illegal in rune literals.

Note that since `rune` is merely an alias for `int32`, you can simply do:

```
var r rune = 0xd8f3
```

instead of

```
var r rune = '\ud8f3'
```

And if you wanted to get a number above 10FFFF you could do

```
var r rune = 0x11ffff
```

instead of

```
var r rune = '\U0011ffff'
```

Answer (score 3):

Already being mentioned, `\ud83f` is part of a surrogate half, used in UTF-16 encoding.
This is not considered a valid code point, and the **[Go specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals)** explicitly states:

> The escapes \u and \U represent Unicode code points so within them
>   some values are illegal, *in particular those above 0x10FFFF and
>   surrogate halves*.

If you want a rune with this invalid code point, you can do the following:

```
c := rune(0xd83f)
```

But, the correct way to handling such a value is to first decode the two surrogate halves, then using the resulting *valid* code point.

Comment: "This is not considered a valid code point" Wrong. Also, you don't need a conversion to assign to c, even if the type was rune instead of default type. I.e, this works: package main;func main() {var r rune = 0xd83f; r=r}

Comment: @HaroldR.Eason Wrong? How does Go consider it valid? Spec might use the word "_illegal_" instead, and I used "not valid" as a synonym. And, of course you need to explicitly specify `rune` or else it will use the default type for the untyped constant (`int` in this case). Your code and mine are equivalent.

Comment: Surrogate code points are valid Unicode code points. I thought you were saying that they are invalid in general (as opposed to invalid in Go). Second point: I was just pointing out that you don't need the conversion in the actual real case where the user would be using a rune (or int type...). The conversion implies the one who wrote the code mistakenly believes that a value of type `rune` is an abstraction of a Unicode code point instead of merely an `int32`.

Comment: @HaroldR.Eason I never said it _isn't_ a code point. It is. It is just not a valid one. No UTF can encode it. And since `int` and `int32` are two different types, you still need explicitly specify `rune` (or `int32`) if you want a rune/int32.

Comment: Python `>>> u"\ud83f".encode("utf8")'` outputs `'\xed\xa0\xbf'`. Even Go considers this valid: `fmt.Println([]byte(string([]rune{0xd83f})))` outputs `[239 191 189]`. As you can see the restriction is only syntactic. No idea what your second point is about.

Comment: @HaroldR.Eason It is invalid UTF-8 according to the [UTF-8 specs](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629). The output you get is the UTF-8 encoding of the _replacement character_, not 0xd83f. Go can handle invalid code points correctly. I am not sure what Python is doing though.

Comment: Really? I never knew that, and didn't notice it was encoding U+FFFD.  Is it only UTF-8 that has that restriction? But isn't the point of the surrogate code points to capture failed UTF-16 decoding? Some UTF-16 might be just 0xD9,0x00 (or reverse if little endian), and then it would decode to U+D900, but then when you UTF-8 encode it, the information is simply lost (except for in Python). I tested Java and it also converts to U+FFFD.

Comment: @HaroldR.Eason I think it goes for all UTF. If you only have 0xD9, 0x00, then it is an invalid UTF-16 sequence as well ([Specs](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2781.txt): "sequences involving surrogate pairs that have illegal values or unpaired surrogates"), and the encoder/decoder should take that into account.